# Change ES6 global import to named import in whole project - [refactoring]

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, refactoring, node-modules, ramda.js

I use global imports of ramda library as R

`import * as R from 'ramda'`

`R.identity(1)`

I want to use it like below

`import { identity } from 'ramda'`

`identity(1)`

Is there easy way to refactor it using visual-studio-code, webstorm or any other tool, maybe bash script (I have to replace every ramda method)?

Comment: Do you need some smart refactoring? If no, Find & Replace with Regex will be enough I think.

Comment: Before refactoring, think that to write `identity(1)` is difficut to identify the source library. `ramda.identify(1)` allow to identify the source library by reading the code

Comment: I have to replace every method from ramda. Application is modular, and ramda is pretty much only library there so no reason not to get rid of `R.`

Comment: why do you need this? reducing bundle size?

Comment: no, refactoring. I want the code to be cleaner without `R` `R.map -> map` `R.reduce -> reduce`